# Why ThreadLocal.ThreadLocalMap use Entry Array instead of Single Entry to save data？

Tags: java, thread-safety

when we use ThreadLocal.set(value), we just save only one value by using the same key, so why ThreadLocalMap use Entry[] but not Entry to save value?

Comment: It doesn't. The `Entry[]` table is used by the internal class `ThreadLocalMap`, which is associated with the `Thread`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ThreadLocalMap` is a hash table that maintains all of the `ThreadLocal` objects associated with a thread, not just a single item. This table is stored in the package-private `Thread.threadLocals` instance variable.

`ThreadLocal.set` updates the value within the `Thread.threadLocals` map: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/lang/ThreadLocal.java#l190

Answer (score 0):

because Thread can set multiple val

`ThreadLocalMap.set(ThreadLocal<?> key, Object value)`

the key is ThreadLocal, so thread can set multiple val by different ThreadLocal